# Fetch Data from MySQL with (ORDER BY & WHERE) in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I want to fetch data from MySQL database but I'm getting an exception because my query is not correct.
I want to fetch data of a particular user by using their username as a condition.

Here is the query that I'm using:

```
String userName = "student1" ;
String query = "SELECT * FROM `result` ORDER BY score DESC WHERE username = " +userName;
```

Here is the exception that I'm getting.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE username = student1' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

Comment: `ORDER BY ` comes after `WHERE`

Comment: I'd suggest testing your SQL queries with a database client before using them in your code, you'll detect that kind of errors earlier.

Comment: Note that `String query = "... WHERE username = " +userName;` has at least 2 potential issues: 1) the query would be vulnerable to SQL injection (assuming `userName` isn't actually hardcoded like in your example 2) the string doesn't contain any quotes so the database will try to interpret it as something other than a string - it will most likely complain about the column `student1` not being found (the resulting query would look like `"... WHERE username = student1"`). - Note that this applies once you've fixed your current problem with `ORDER BY` being in the wrong place.

Comment: can you please write above query in correct format

Answer (score 1):

Change your string of query like below,

```
String userName = "student1" ;
String query = "SELECT * FROM `result` WHERE username = " + userName + " ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The correct order for query writing is WGHO where
W - where clause
G - group by clause
H - having clause
O - order by clause